# I want help in adding a new service in my simple android app

Tags: android, service

This is the code i have created and is simple activity that shows current location of user art regular intervals on a  button click. I want to make it a service so that when i click on button, it starts the service that keeps on fetching the user's current location but i am not able to do that. Can some one help me in doing it. This is the code for MainActivity.java.

```
  package com.maps.saury.location;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
            OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
        BGTask bgtask=new BGTask(this);
        // LogCat tag
        private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

        private Location mLastLocation;

        // Google client to interact with Google API
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

        // boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
        private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

        // Location updates intervals in sec
        private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 100; // 10 sec
        private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 100; // 5 sec
        private static int DISPLACEMENT = 0; // 10 meters

        // UI elements
        private TextView lblLocation;
        private Button btnShowLocation, btnStartLocationUpdates;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLocation);
            btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
            btnStartLocationUpdates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocationUpdates);

            // First we need to check availability of play services
            if (checkPlayServices()) {

                // Building the GoogleApi client
                buildGoogleApiClient();

                createLocationRequest();
            }

            // Show location button click listener
            btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    displayLocation();
                }
            });

            // Toggling the periodic location updates
            btnStartLocationUpdates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    togglePeriodicLocationUpdates();
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            checkPlayServices();

            // Resuming the periodic location updates
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }

        /**
         * Method to display the location on UI
         * */
        private void displayLocation() {

            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);
                BGTask bgtask=new BGTask(this);
                bgtask.execute(Double.toString(latitude),Double.toString(longitude));

            } else {

                lblLocation
                        .setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Method to toggle periodic location updates
         * */
        private void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {
            if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
                // Changing the button text
                btnStartLocationUpdates
                        .setText(getString(R.string.btn_stop_location_updates));

                mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

                // Starting the location updates
                startLocationUpdates();

                Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates started!");

            } else {
                // Changing the button text
                btnStartLocationUpdates
                        .setText(getString(R.string.btn_start_location_updates));

                mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

                // Stopping the location updates
                stopLocationUpdates();

                Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates stopped!");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Creating google api client object
         * */
        protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        }

        /**
         * Creating location request object
         * */
        protected void createLocationRequest() {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
        }

        /**
         * Method to verify google play services on the device
         * */
        private boolean checkPlayServices() {
            int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                    .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                            PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    finish();
                }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Starting the location updates
         * */
        protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates( mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        }

        /**
         * Stopping location updates
         */
        protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

        /**
         * Google api callback methods
         */
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                    + result.getErrorCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

            // Once connected with google api, get the location
            displayLocation();

            if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Assign the new location
            mLastLocation = location;


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Locatn changed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Displaying the new location on UI
            displayLocation();
        }


    }
```

This is my Activity_Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/view_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/marker" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/lbl_you_are_at"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShowLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@color/btn_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_get_location"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLocationUpdates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@color/btn_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_start_location_updates"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you add some most promising trial from you, that unfortunately did not work out, I am sure people will find it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
First Check your Manifest.xml and check Internet permission.

<permission
        android:name="com.hamms.cabsystem.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Second Check google Map Api Meta data.
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBBGHOC13C00ew4xKD7kyei0M3bul8093s" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Then, Create on ServiceClass like this and start Service on click of button.


btn_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

           startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));

}
}

public class MyService extend Service{

onstartCommand(){

Intent i = new Intent(youraction);
sendBroadCast(i);

}

In Myservice onStartCommand Method Send OneBraodcast which is update your location.

Register Brodcast Receiver in Manifest,xml
 <receiver android:name="MyBroadCast"></receiver>

public class MyBroadCast extend BrodcastReciver{

 // here onRecive Method you upadate your location.
// do something here // 

}
```

Comment: That  all i know but there's so much code in mainactivity.java, not able to decide what to put inside service class .